# Proving $u+\frac1{n}$ is an upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be non-empty.  Show that if $u=\sup S$, then $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, u-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound of of $S$ but $u+\frac1{n}$ is an upper bound of $S$.

So we start that since $u=\sup S$, $u$ is an upper bound of $S$, and is, in particular the least upper bound of $S$.  Therefore, there is no smaller number than $u$ that can be a lower bound.  Since $u-\frac1{n}<u$, $u$ cannot be an upper bound of $S$.  For $u+\frac1{n}$, since $u$ is the supremum, $s\le u, \forall s \in S$.  So
$$s\le u \lt u+\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow s<u+\frac1{n},\forall s\in S, \forall \in \mathbb{N}$$
Therefore, by definition, $u+\frac1{n}$ is an upper bound of $S$.

Is this a good proof?

Comment: You wrote: Therefore there is no smaller number than u that can be a lower bound. The last two words of that line will be upper bound not lower bound.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant....thanks Rana!

Answer (score 2):

Change "that can be a lower bound" to "that can be an upper bound".

Change "Since $u−1/n<u$, $u$ cannot..." to "Therefore, since $u−1/n<u$, $u- 1/n$ cannot...".

Change "$s \le u \forall s \in S$ to $\forall s\in S, s \le u$.

Remove the "$\forall n \in N$" from the displayed equation: you're doing everything here for a particular $n \in N$. In fact, you should start with "Let $n \in N$ be a fixed positive integer."

Comment: so other than those errors (which I feel as though I meant to say but perhaps didn't write correctly), the logic is correct?

Comment: It looks good to me, yes. And I'm sure you *did* mean to write those things, but that's why you're writing proofs (and we're helping you): until you *do* write exactly the right things, your proofs aren't really proofs. And a "sort of proof" doesn't really do much good (except to the reader who already knows how to prove something for him/herself!).

Comment: Ha ha!  Yeah, I guess you're right!  I really have trouble thinking logically when it comes to math, so this site is very helpful to put my try in, and see where the holes in my arguments are...I feel like this is helping me.